# How to change the background color of `TextCell` inside `ListView` in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I have a `ListView` set up like below:

```
<ListView HasUnevenRows="true" BackgroundColor="Gray">
    <ListView.Header>
        <StackLayout Padding="20,35,20,10" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Label FontSize="13" TextColor="Gray" Text="Header text here"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ListView.Header>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <ListView.DataTemplate>
            <TextCell Text="{Binding CategoryName}" Detail="{Binding Count}">
        </ListView.DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

I have a renderer for iOS and set the following:

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell(Cell item, UITableViewCell reusableCell, UITableView tv)
{
    var cell = base.GetCell(item, reusableCell, tv);
    cell.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;
    return cell;
}
```

Somehow my whole `ListView` is using the `Gray` background I set for the listview. What I want to happen is have a `Gray` color background for the `ListView` (which means the header part would have a gray background) and have `Red` color background for the `TextCell`. Am I setting the wrong property to get the desired background for `TextCell`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your custom renderer is not actually returning the cell, so the change you make to the `BackgroundColor` is not coming through.

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell(Cell item, UITableViewCell reusableCell, UITableView tv)
{
    var cell = base.GetCell(item, reusableCell, tv);        
    cell.ContentView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;
    return cell;
}
```

Update: You should be setting `cell.ContentView.BackgroundColor` instead.

Comment: Sorry I just missed that part. I typed the sample code directly here. But in my project I did return the `cell`. Thanks

Comment: This answer did not help me. Please refer to my reply to him. Thanks.

Comment: I updated the answer. You should be setting `cell.ContentView.BackgroundColor`. There might be better solutions though where a custom renderer is not necessary like mentioned in the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Add your textcell inside Grid/StackLayout and assign `BackgroundColor="Red"` 
 for corresponding layout directly in the xaml. Your don't need to write custom renderer for that.

Comment: I believe the `DataTemplate` for a `ListView` must inherit from a `Cell`. So I cannot wrap a `StackLayout` around my `TextCell`.

Comment: Instead of textcell you can use entry.