# How to change backgroundColor to item in ListView?

Tags: c#, xamarin, colors, xamarin.forms

I'm using CustomCell for item in ListView.
CustomCell is used as TextCell in DataTemplate.
How to change backgroundColor when that item is selected?
Items are filled from api so its dinamic.
I was trying to use Focused event but its not working.
Thanks for help

```
public class CustomCell : ViewCell
{
    StackLayout cellWrapper = new StackLayout();
    public CustomCell()
    {
        StackLayout titleStack = new StackLayout();
        StackLayout horizontalLayout = new StackLayout();
        Label Tittle = new Label();
        Label Detail = new Label();
        Label Detail2 = new Label();

        Tittle.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Title");
        Detail.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Datail");
        Detail2.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Detail2");

        cellWrapper.BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#fff");
        horizontalLayout.Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal;
        cellWrapper.Padding = 10;

        Tittle.TextColor = Color.FromHex("#000");
        Detail.TextColor = Color.FromHex("#a59f9f");
        Tittle.FontSize = 20;


        titleStack.Children.Add(Tittle);
        horizontalLayout.Children.Add(Detail);
        horizontalLayout.Children.Add(Detail2);

        cellWrapper.Children.Add(titleStack);
        cellWrapper.Children.Add(horizontalLayout);
        cellWrapper.Focused += CellWrapper_Focused;

        View = cellWrapper;
    }

    private void CellWrapper_Focused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.IsFocused)
        {
            cellWrapper.BackgroundColor = Color.Blue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the background color of \`TextCell\` inside \`ListView\` in Xamarin Forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43799766/how-to-change-the-background-color-of-textcell-inside-listview-in-xamarin-fo)

Comment: Thats only for IOS

Comment: Use theme in android or just google - https://www.google.co.in/search?q=xamarin+forms+textcell+selected+item+background+color&rlz=1C5CHFA_enIN744IN744&oq=xamarin+forms+textcell+selected+item+background+color&aqs=chrome..69i57.13790j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

I think you can have a "Selected" boolean property in your Model.

When SelectedItem is rised, you can set "Selected" property to "true".

Bind Background color property to "Selected" property... then, with a IValueConverter, convert the boolean "true" value to your "selected color", and "false" value to "unselected" color.

Remember to Unselect the previous selected item when a new one is selected.

For example, this can be your Model

```
namespace TestSelectedItemInListView
{
    [ImplementPropertyChanged]
    public class MyModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }

        public bool Selected { get; set; }

        public MyModel()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

this the converter

```
public class SelectedToColorConverter : IValueConverter
{

    #region IValueConverter implementation

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is bool)
        {
            if ((Boolean)value)
                return Color.Red;
            else
                return Color.Black;
        }
        return Color.Black;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

this is the SelectedItem property in ViewModel

```
    public MyModel SelectedItem
    {
        get { return _selectedItem; }
        set
        {
            if (_selectedItem != null)
                _selectedItem.Selected = false;

            _selectedItem = value;

            if (_selectedItem != null)
            {
                _selectedItem.Selected = true;
                MessagingCenter.Send<MasterPageViewModel, string>(this, "Detail", _selectedItem.Name);
            }
        }
    }
```

You can find a repo [TestSelectedItemInListView](https://github.com/acaliaro/TestSelectedItemInListView)